# наложение полупрозрачного фона на блок с окошком в центре

Tags: html, css, css3

Доброго времени - потребовалось реализовать занятную задачу. Есть у меня блок в нем может быть текст, картинка или пр. Надо наложить на него полупрозрачный фон к примеру я использую rgba ну или opacity для этого фона, НО что бы по центру в опционально настроенном месте осталось окошко, задача напоминает, тот момент когда в Контакте ставишь себе изображение профиля там как раз похожее выполнение, только там оно еще и двигается, попробовал сделать 4 отдельных блока с прозрачным бэкграундом, абсолютно спозиционированных - сверху, слева, снизу и с права, так что бы они и образовывали в центре это "открытое" окошко но такая реализация выглядит черезчур топорно, как можно это реализовать более по человечески?

Comment: в контакте по видимому сделано так как во всяких плагинах для обрезки картинок. но так, как я понимаю, просто грузят одну и ту же картинку в разные слои. вам такой механизм не очень удобен будет

Comment: @splash58 , хм да к стати я подозревал что там что то с gd2 намудрено

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var selector = $('div.image-selector div.selector');
var img = $('div.image-selector img.original');
img.width(img.width()).clone().removeClass('original').addClass('copy').appendTo(selector);
selector.on('change', function() {
  $(this).find('img.copy').css({
    'margin-left': '-' + $(this).css('left'),
    'margin-top': '-' + $(this).css('top')
  });
});
selector.animate({
  left: 320,
  top: 200
}, {
  duration: 3000,
  progress: function() {
    selector.trigger('change');
  }
});
```

```css
div.image-selector {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #999;
  position: relative;
}
div.image-selector img.original {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: block;
}
div.image-selector div.selector {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: #FFF 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-selector">
  <img class="original" src="http://www.coolwebmasters.com/uploads/posts/2013-09/1378894260_background-07.jpg" />
  <div class="selector"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не знаю, верно ли ты сделал. но мне нравится!)